# JAVAFX: How to get different MenuItems in a MenuButton when the option changes in another MenuButton

Tags: java, javafx

```
MenuItem opt1 = new MenuItem("Opt1");
MenuItem opt2= new MenuItem("Opt2");
MenuButton menu = new MenuButton("Menu");
menu.getItems.(opt1,opt2);

VBox mmm= new VBox();
mmm.getChildren.add(menu);


MenuItem subOpt1= new MenuItem("SubOpt1");
MenuItem subOpt2= new MenuItem("SubOpt2");
MenuButton sbuMenu = new MenuButton("subMenu");
menu.getItems.(SubOpt1,SubOpt2);

MenuItem subOpt001= new MenuItem("SubOpt001");
MenuItem subOpt002= new MenuItem("SubOpt002");
MenuButton subMenu00 = new MenuButton("subMenu00");
menu.getItems.(SubOpt001,SubOpt002);

opt1.setOnAction(e->{

    if(e.getSource==opt1)
        mmm.getChildren.add(subMenu);


})


opt1.setOnAction(e->{

    if(e.getSource==opt2)
        mmm.getChildren.add(subMenu00);


})
```

Then I run the app and only shows the menu the MenuItem, and nothing else shows up.
Another method I use is that declare a global variable `MenuButton sub` and the value changes as the action set on MenuItem `opt1` and `opt2` changes. Then  using a vbox to `.addAll(menu,sub)`, and error shows `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

How to get different MenuItems in a  MenuButton when the option changes in another MenuButton

Comment: Probably caused by modifying a menu that is displayed. Maybe you can do a workaround by only enabling those items you should have access to. Furthermore to represent this state of the menu using a `CheckMenuItem`/`RadioMenuItem` would be more appropriate. BTW: since you're replacing `opt1`'s `onAction` handler with a handler that checks, if the source is `opt2` you shouldn't see any effects like those described.

Comment: Maybe a `menuButton` can be covered by another using `.setVisible()`, but it seems there's no way to cover a button with another? Or there's some specific pane can make this happen? After coming up with these that seem as a solution,I tried and failed. Same reason of what @fabian said, I'm modifying the pane displayed. However, `image.setVisible()` is working after the pane is showed. Why and how can I fix this????  Also, I use `VBox` to contain these menuButtons, and the `.setLayOutX/Y` doesn't work, the `menuButton` cannot be covered. Any advice??

Comment: It is just like you're in the station and choose the start place and the end. First giving the lines they have and then based on the line you've chosen, you can only see the position on this line. How can this work???

Comment: @fabian Maybe it's not what you say about modifying the displayed thing. When I use a `button.setOnMouseClicked(e->{ someImage.setVisible(true) 
     anotherImage.setVisible(false)})` IT IS WORKING!!! So I think it's the problem about the actionEnvent, how can this problem be solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set every `MenuButton` in the same place and when the `MenuItem` of the 1st `MenuButton` is selected, change the ***visibility*** (`.setVisble()`)of the other `MenuButtons` you wanna hide and appear, it works. `Deatils` are in the comment.